# HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request - While Searching Employee based on Form Field

Tags: spring-mvc

```
  Hi i am trying to search employee based <input> tag of<form>field.Field details get from DB and I am trying to fetch it's record. But it shows following error
```

**Error**

**HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request**

Type Status Report

***Description*** The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

**My Controller**

```
  package com.nt.controller;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


     import com.nt.command.SearchCommand;
     import com.nt.dto.SearchDTO;
     import com.nt.dto.SearchResultDTO;
     import com.nt.service.EmployeeSearchService;

    @Controller
     public class EmployeeSearchController {
          @Autowired
           private EmployeeSearchService service; 

@RequestMapping("/performsearch.htm")
public String search(Map<String,Object>map,@ModelAttribute SearchCommand command){
    SearchDTO dto=null;
    List<SearchResultDTO> listRDTO=null;
    System.out.println("EmployeeSearchController.search()");
    //Convert Command obj DTO class obj
    dto=new SearchDTO();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(command,dto);
    // use Servie classs
    listRDTO=service.findEmployees(dto);
    //Keep listRDTO in Map object
    map.put("empList",listRDTO);
    //return  LVN
    return "list_emps";
}

}
```

**Search Jsp**

```
    <h1 style="color:red;text-align:center">Search Emp Details </h1>
       <form action="performsearch.htm" method="POST">
           Eno :: <input type="text"  name="eno"><br>
           Ename :: <input type="text"  name="ename"><br>
           Desg :: <input type="text"  name="desg"><br>
           Salary :: <input type="text"  name="salary"><br>
           <input type="submit"  value="Search Employee Details">
      </form>
```

**Result JSP Page**

```
 <%@ page language="java" isELIgnored="false" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

   <c:choose>
   <c:when test="${!empty empList}">
      <table border="1">
            <tr><th>empno</th><th>ename</th><th>job</th><th>salary</th> 
                 <th>deptno</th><th>mgrno</th></tr>
        <c:forEach var="dto" items="${empList}">
                <tr>
                       <td>${dto.eno}</td>
                       <td>${dto.ename}</td>
                       <td>${dto.job}</td>
                       <td>${dto.salary}</td>
                       <td>${dto.deptno}</td>
                        <td>${dto.mgrNo}</td>
                </tr>
             </c:forEach>
              </table>
```

**spring configuration file**

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

         <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
         <!-- Hanlder mappings -->
          <bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
           <property name="mappings">
              <props>
               <prop key="home.htm">pvc</prop>
             </props>
         </property>
       </bean>



           <!-- Controller classes -->
           <bean id="pvc"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
             <property name="viewName" value="search"/>
        </bean>

           <!-- View Resolvers -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
           <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
          </bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.nt.controller"/>
            <mvc:annotation-driven/>

        </beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context- 
       4.2.xsd">

       <import resource="service-beans.xml"/>
          <import resource="persistence-beans.xml"/>

         </beans>
```

**service-beans.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.nt.service"/>


        </beans>
```

**persistance-beans.xml**

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

      <bean id="jofb"  class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/JNDIDS"/>
      </bean>

         <bean id="template"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="jofb"/>
            </bean>

         <context:component-scan base-package="com.nt.dao"/> 

        </beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
   <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
     "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

        <web-app>
        <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
                 </listener>


      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
           <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>


          </web-app>
```

Comment: add your spring configuration code and do not let the url to contains `.htm`

Comment: but in web.xml i have taken url pattern as ' <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>' then it's mandatory and in my all application taken same url pattern they are working fine and in this application welcome page comming perfectly that's also map with same url...if not take '.htm' then  what should take url pattern..

Comment: I do not see your spring configuration file and also do not add code in comment!

Comment: sorry forgot to add...just added please check

Comment: I don't see <context:component-scan base-package="com.nt.controller"/> in your configuration file? Is that missed ? Can you check?